# Can't fill jtable from resultset java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing, jdbc

With this code the table is filled successfully but without the message dialog nothing inserted to the jtable !

```
String sql2 = "SELECT type, amount FROM lasttransactions where cust_id = ?";
PreparedStatement ps2=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
ps2.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(_userid));
ResultSet rs2=ps2.executeQuery();


DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) transtable.getModel();
Object[] row; String type; double amount ;
while(rs2.next()) {
     type = rs2.getString("type");
     amount = rs2.getDouble("amount");

    row = new Object []{ type, amount };            


    model.addRow(row);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"added !");   


    transtable.setModel(model);
}
```

Comment: Looks okayish (you're not managing your resources very well), consider making a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer Im so sorry Im still beginner so how to manage my resources ?
my problem is nothing loaded to the table without this message line

Comment: The JOptionPane should have no effect on data that is loaded into a TableModel. The only thing I can suggest based on the code provided is to get rid of the setModel(...) method. You are directly update the TableModel of your table so you don't need to set the model.

Comment: If you open a resource, you should close it, have a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

How i did it.May it will help you to solve your problem.

```
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB", "root", "password");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from somewhere;";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  finally {
        rs.close();
    }
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: `rs` might be `null` when you try and close it, you're also not closing the `stmt`, and generally should be using `PreapredStatement` (I know, it's a simple query, but it's also simple to use `PreapredStatement` all the time).  `DbUtils` is, frankly, just a pain and raises more questions on SO then actually manually creating the table model yourself